# Write test output to file in NightwatchJS

Tags: node.js, webdriver, nightwatch.js

I want to write the actual test output of NightwatchJS tests (not the browser console) to a file. I can't seem to find any resource regarding about this.

The **log_path** option is ok, it does log some stuff on the location you specified after the test, but its not the same data vs the actual test output.

below is my nightwatch.json file

```
{
  "src_folders" : [ 
  "tests" , 
  "tests/settings/general" 
],

"page_objects_path" : [ 
  "page_objects/backend" , 
  "page_objects/frontend" ,
  "page_objects/backend/settings/general"
],

"globals_path" : "./nightwatch.globals.js",

"webdriver" : {
  "start_process" : true,
  "log_path"      : "./logs"
},

"test_settings" : {

  "default" : {
    "webdriver": {
      "server_path" : "node_modules/.bin/chromedriver",
      "port"        : 9515,
      "cli_args"    : [ "--log" , "debug" ]
    },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName"         : "chrome",
      "acceptInsecureCerts" : true,
      "javascriptEnabled"   : true,
      "acceptSslCerts"      : true
    }
  },

  "firefox" : {
    "webdriver": {
      "server_path" : "node_modules/.bin/geckodriver",
      "port"        : 4444,
      "cli_args"    : [ "--log" , "debug" ]
    },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName"         : "firefox",
      "acceptInsecureCerts" : true,
      "javascriptEnabled"   : true,
      "acceptSslCerts"      : true
    }
  }

}
```

}

Hope you can help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could add '> tests_output/Test_filename.txt' after the command to run the test. So, I have my package.json file set up with the script 'test' for running Nightwatch. My terminal input to save the output as a file would look like this:

```
npm test > /tests_output/testRun100720.txt
```

This will place the output file I name testRun100720.txt into the tests_output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more detail of what you mean by 'output'?

In the meantime, try adding `"output_folder": "reports/",` to your json file, this should generate XML output from the Nightwatch logger which may provide more details.

Comment: What I mean is what you see on the command line during test run, I want that same output be feed into a file. I already tried the recommendation above but the output it spits on the file specified on the "output_folder" is not the same with the output it spits on the command line during test run.